# Set up configuration for external display

Tags: release-freya, display

I have a laptop and quite frequently I connect and disconnect external monitor. The monitor always has wrong configuration (main display is on laptop and display placement is wrong) on connection, so I have to set it up manually.

Is it possible to set configuration for the display, so I wouldn't set it up manually everytime on connection?